# programmatically creating button in android with click event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am creating a dynamically buttons when one button is clicked. i.e. under onClick event of that button. But it is creating n number of button dynamically for every click one button is created.

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
.....

public void onClick(View arg0) {
Button topArtistbutton = new Button(SalesPanel.this, null,android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
topArtistbutton.setText("Top Artist");
topArtistbutton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));topArtistbutton.setId(3);
ll.addView(topArtistbutton);
}
```

i want only one button created dynamically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
boolean bCreate = true;
...
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (bCreate)
    {
         Button topArtistbutton = new Button(SalesPanel.this, null,android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
         topArtistbutton.setText("Top Artist");
         topArtistbutton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));topArtistbutton.setId(3);
         ll.addView(topArtistbutton);
         bCreate = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the flag and use if statement to check whether button is already created or not:

```
boolean created = false;


public void onClick(View arg0) {
if (!created) {

    Button topArtistbutton = new Button(SalesPanel.this, null,android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
    topArtistbutton.setText("Top Artist");
    topArtistbutton.setLayoutParams(new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    topArtistbutton.setId(3);
    ll.addView(topArtistbutton);
    created = true;
    }
}
```